# Cloning "By": Defensive Programming with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, defensive-copy

So I'm writing a Panel Object API for a website I'm testing with Selenium, and since this one is likely to be used by many people outside of my control in the future, I thought I may as well make it defensive (as seen in Effective Java). However, I've hit a wall when it comes to returning a clone of By.

I was expecting a method like arrayList has:

```
By newBy = new By(oldBy);
```

Doesn't exist as By is made statically. Further, I don't know of any way to get the information out of a By once the information is in there except for `toString()`. So I can write a parser for `By.toString()`, but that seems like a lot of effort for what the job is, and not very elegant to boot.

Can anyone suggest a less cumbersome way of cloning a By locator in selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### mind you, this is simply an alternative.

In terms of defensive programming, one thing I could recommend to you, which i've done in several other automation frameworks using Selenium...

Is to wrap the `driver.findElement` then accept only CSS selectors, IDs, Xpath, whatever you want.  An example would be this:

```
@Config(
    url="http://wordpress.org",
    browser = Browser.CHROME
)
public class GettingStarted extends AutomationTest {
    @Test
    public void testSeleniumHQ() {
        navigateTo("http://docs.seleniumhq.org")
        .click("a[title='Selenium Projects']")
        .click(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'bigMenu')]//p/a[@href='webdriver/']"))
        .validateTextPresent("Selenium 1.0 + WebDriver = Selenium 2.0")
        ;
    }
}
```

*(exerpt from [this class](https://github.com/ddavison/aa-selenium-meetup/blob/master/src/main/java/selenium/GettingStarted.java#L17) using the [Getting Started with Selenium framework](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium-framework))*

In here, `click` is overloaded to accept a String (CSS selector) but can also accept the `By` class.

If you want all of your developers to use one thing in particular, instead of accepting a `By`, just make it accept a String, and the String HAS to be CSS, an ID, or Xpath (whatever you prefer).   This would make it a little cleaner, and definitely more consolidated.  (Your testers would be forced to use CSS or whatever you choose)

Comment: Expanding @sircapsalot idea on the long term I'd force it to accept just `ID` as CSS selectors doesn't need to be unique and could lead to false positives and `Xpath` may vary due design changes. From my experience sites are alive creatures and this approach would reduce the maintenance of your test-suite as long as ID's don't change

Comment: Unfortunately, however, not all elements have ID's.  If this was the case for your app, then specifying an ID would NOT be the best option, unless it's in your requirements to ID all elements.

Comment: Looking again at By (I don't know how I've never realised that it isn't an abstract class before), would it make sense to have an abstract wrapper class with subclasses for each variation, allowing for the variants?

Answer (score 0):

`By` is an abstract class. As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18146403/2129082) you can't create deep clone of abstract class because they can't be instantiated. You can take a look at the suggested hack though but I think you don't need to be so defensive