# How to clone an object which is extended from an abstract class?

Tags: java, object, interface, clone, abstract

I think the call "super.clone()" doesn't go to the Cloneable class but to the abstract class..

```
public class Mainprogramm { 
  Test original = new Test();
 Test copy = original.getClone();
}

public class Test extends AbstractClass implements Cloneable{
  public Test getClone(){
  try
    {
        return (Test) super.clone();
    }
    catch(CloneNotSupportedException a)
    {   
        return this;
    }
  }
}

public class AbstractClass implements Cloneable{
  //no abstract clone-method...
}
```

Comment: What problems is this code having?

Comment: Besides your Mainprogram not compiling. Please post *real* code with your questions, not kind-of/sort-of code.

Comment: [Somewhat related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146319/java-cloning-abstract-objects)

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking **wrong**:

*I think the call "super.clone()" doesn't go to the Cloneable class but to the abstract class.*

The point is: **Cloneable** is just an **interface**. And its presence does something completely different; see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html):

*A class implements the Cloneable interface to indicate to the Object.clone() method that it is legal for that method to make a field-for-field copy of instances of that class.*

In other words: you better study the **concepts** you intend to use; instead of just putting down some code and wondering what it might be doing. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081858/about-java-cloneable) for example.

In that sense: yes, `super.clone()` does "go" to the abstract base class; but: that is the only place where you actually can call clone() on.

Comment: In case my formulation wasn't unequivocally to you, I'm sorry, but the code I wrote doesn't work (I get an nullpointer exception) and I would like to know how I have to rewrite it.

Comment: Do you mean I should programm it like this:

Comment: public Test getClone() { return new Test(this)}

Comment: I mean you **read** the second link I put in my answer. As long and as often as it takes to understand what this interface is about, and how it works.